# how to delete from multipe tables using primary and foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete whole data by id.
I have two tables
`student` and `addresss`.
I set address primary key as foreign key in student table
I tried like this:

```
delete  stud
from student as stud inner join address_Table as addd on addd.aid = stud.aid 
where id = 142
```

This query is deleting data of only in student table.

Comment: Check out FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: I think you have to set student id as foreign key in address table

Comment: i am using sql server @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: while inserting data i am first inserting into address table then geting id of address table then inserting id into student tables. in same way i want to delete the data  @AbhilashRavindranCK

Comment: It does say `delete stud`

Comment: yes,deleteting data from student table  @Paparazzi

Comment: A suggested other solution is to make a view and delete from that.

Answer (score 0):

Following information will be useful to you,

- You can only delete from one table with a single delete statement in Sql Server.
- If you need to delete from both tables, then you have to use a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade.( Here you have to set studentid in `address` table as foreign key references studentid(primary key of `student` table) in `student` table.